# Running out of memory despite plenty virtual and physical available on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, memory, dualboot

I am having an issue that my programs crash often with out-of-memory errors.

My memory spec:
32GB total RAM
64GB starting page file
128GB max page file

With these huge values, I still get out of memory errors and my programs are often crashing while running just a few tabs in Chrome for example. Could this be related to somehow messing up while installing GRUB and/or general dual boot usage or some Windows corruption? My Linux runs just fine.

[image: task manager view]

UPDATE:

After while running idle my virtual memory usage actually spikes to more than 50 GB.

after running query suggested here: https://superuser.com/a/1373217/882391

```
Get-Process | Sort PagedMemorySize-Desc | Select Name, PagedMemorySize, VirtualMemorySize -First 10
```

Output is all instances of svchost suggesting issue is indeed with the operating system or some kind of virus. Will keep this updated.

[image]

Comment: “Could this be related to somehow messing up while installing GRUB and/or general dual boot usage or some Windows corruption?” - No; What error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: It sounds more like a bad memory stick, or maybe even windows swapping to a disk that has bad sectors.

Comment: >  What error message are you getting exactly? ;

General Out of memory errors, either Windows stating it directly by popup error or apps crashing or for example chrome killing a tab stating there is not enough memory

Comment: > It sounds more like a bad memory stick, or maybe even windows swapping to a disk that has bad sectors.; 
How would I test for that? Why it does not happen on Linux?

Comment: Are the programs getting out of memory errors 32-bit? What programs are giving errors?

Comment: If possible, please provide a screenshot of an actual error message you see. When you get the error, try to create a new screenshot of Task Manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows says RAM ran out while there is still 4 GB of physical memory available](https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available)

Comment: see also: https://superuser.com/questions/1170481/out-of-memory-when-plenty-available

Comment: see also: https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available

Comment: and finally: https://superuser.com/questions/1024966/getting-out-of-memory-errors-when-around-65-used-in-windows-10

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket it is actually the same error from https://superuser.com/questions/1170481/out-of-memory-when-plenty-available (just in English, not Chinese ) but I have 128GB of virtual memory, most of it free. No idea how I would exceed that. An no, all programs are 64-bit

Comment: @PapeK24 Yes, and I find the single answer to that question to not be too satisfying... although I'm glad that individual got things working better.

Comment: BTW, MemInfo (https://www.carthagosoft.net/MemInfo.php) can sometimes help a bit when trying to diagnose issues like this.  It's fairly simple, but when I used it in the past, I found it to be accurate.  It includes a function to help defragment/release unused memory blocks as well.

Comment: Nice, that seems like a nice simple tool. I'll run it and try to pinpoint when the issues happen. Also, ran a virus and malware scan. Did not use windows for a while and forgot these things exist :D . Will keep you guys updated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you prolly also want to do a few scans with the windows memory diagnostic tools, and perhaps memtestx86. windows does have per-processes limits on memory allocation but that would be unlikely to come up except with the occasional large application being heavily used.

Comment: See (by searching is settings) *View Reliability History* or *Problem Reports*. Both will show you the same error report. Copy it in full. EG a program can only go down so many levels such as when search a folder tree. How many is random (but large). If you hit it, depending on programming language, you will get *Out of memory*, *Out of stack space*, or *Could not allocate ...*.

Comment: Memory means one of three things. Physical memory, virtual memory, and memory address space. Memory address space is how a program sees memory. It sees a (for 32 bit) a 4 GB contiguous address space - 0 to 4 GB. At any particular address there may be physical memory, hard disk memory (or both), or no memory. If you try to use that address windows will map a physical page of memory to it.

Comment: In your screenshot. Only the bar graph talks about memory from a memory management perspective (hover over the 4 different segments of the bar graph). The other figures are calculated above and below the bar graph to try to give context to what is happening.